# Entry widget row expansion in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk, tkinter-entry

[image]

I designed a chatbot interface but the entry row looks very narrow, so I want to make it widen (2 rows) . I tried with rowspan=2 but it's the same. Below is my code.

self.usr_input = ttk.Entry(self, width=100,  state='normal')

self.usr_input.grid(column=0, row=10, rowspan=2, sticky='nwsw', padx=3, pady=3)

Comment: An Entry is a single-line input area.  You'd need to use a Text instead to get multi-line input.

Comment: Additionally, it's filling 2 rows... but the second row contains only that object which must be one row, and isn't requiring the row to be taller.